# How do I give attribution to pictures in a powerpoint slide presentation?

Tags: legal, authorship

How do I give attribution to pictures in a powerpoint slide presentation? I use several images in a powerpoint slide presentation I prepared, and they're from Google Image Search, what are some proper ways to give attribution to the images without those attribution being too invasive (how do I make them as little invasive as possible, least noticeable) without running the risk of some legal issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that there are two negative aspects of using such pictures:

1. Legal: Though if the ppt is not on the net, you would hardly face it.
2. Possible negative impression on people seeing that ppt.

There are many websites that offer free stock pictures, and there is not copyright issues with those. At the end of ther presentation, you can even write a sentence - "Image courtesy of "site's name".

Some of these stock pics sites are:

https://www.pexels.com
https://unsplash.com
https://pixabay.com
https://www.stockvault.net
https://www.freepik.com
https://www.freeimages.com

More of such at https://www.canva.com/learn/free-stock-photos/

Hope this helps.